# Ender 3 Pro: X-axis moves too much during printing

Tags: creality-ender-3, ultimaker-cura, axis, x-axis, ender3

I got an Ender 3 Pro yesterday and have been having a problem with all of my prints. Whenever the extrusion stops and the X-axis moves, it moves too far. For example, I tried printing a Benchy with 2 skirt lines, and the lines were the right size but too far apart *(I measured it and they turned out to be 5 mm apart)*.
To be clear, this issue only occurs when I'm printing something. When I use the 'move axis' function on the X-axis, it moves appropriately.

- Is this a problem with the G-code/slicer or the printer?
- What is causing this and how do I fix it?

Update: I've attached a picture of this. I threw the original Benchy in the trash so I made another one. I'll keep experimenting and see if I can fix it.
[image: Picture of an uncompleted first layer of a 3D Benchy. The skirt lines around the model are noticeably far apart.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - Is this a problem with the G-code/slicer or the printer?

The issue came from the way I assembled my printer, not from the G-code or slicer that I was using.

> - What is causing this and how do I fix it?

It turns out that I put the belt on the X-axis upside down, and that was causing it to move incorrectly. I detached the belt from the 2 points that it was clipped onto, then re-applied it correctly and tightly, and now I can print things properly.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer! You can accept the answer after 48 hours! Many thanks for sharing your experience, this may help others in the future! If I correctly understand the issue, were the belts 180° turned at the ends?

Comment: So the belts were riding on the smooth side, rather than notched in the pulleys? Oh well, don't feel too bad. On the woodworking forum people occasionally post that their table saw isn't cutting well, and they have the blade in backwards...